# Machine replies to "arp_requests" for internal addresses even though "net.ipv4.conf.<intf>.arp_ignore" is configured to disable this

Tags: networking, sysctl, arp

I current have a node with an interface connected to the internet (through a VLAN). I will refer to these as `eth0` and `eth0.100`, with the latter being the VLAN interface in the machine.

I preemptively setup routes on the host such as:

```
10.250.100.92 dev <internal interface> proto static scope host table 99
```

Note that the scope is set to `host` here, and that this is not in the `main` routing table, but rather table `99`. I have `ip rule`s setup to use this other table.

I also have set the following `sysctl` options:

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_ignore=3
net.ipv4.conf.eth0/100.arp_ignore=3
```

From the documentation for this option, I see the following:

```
arp_ignore - INTEGER
    Define different modes for sending replies in response to
    received ARP requests that resolve local target IP addresses:
    0 - (default): reply for any local target IP address, configured
    on any interface
    <<<<< SKIPPED OTHER OPTIONS FOR BREVITY >>>>>
    3 - do not reply for local addresses configured with scope host,
    only resolutions for global and link addresses are replied
```

It looks like my machine should not reply for the ARP request for this address, as the route has `scope host`. However, when ARP requests come in through `eth0`/`eth0.100`, the machine still sends out an ARP reply. Is there a separate configuration step I am missing? Based on the documentation above (`do not reply for local addresses configured with scope host`), the machine should not be sending an ARP reply for this address.

Edit: It seems like the `ip route` is the issue. I have a proxy-ARP entry that is supposed to be the source of truth for whether or not an ARP reply should be sent. Is it possible to have the ARP replies "ignore" `ip route`s?

Comment: I think the “scope host” thing there refers to the scope of the _address_, not the scope of a route. What does `ip -o a sh dev <internal interface> | grep -E 'scope [^ ]+ ‘` say?

Comment: @LL3 so the thing about my setup is that this address is actually not assigned to any interface; the `ip route` entry will forward the packet to an interface automatically. That being said, I did try to see what would happen. I added an address to this interface (the same one the route is configured with), and even when adding it with a `scope host`, as long as the `ip route` entry exists, I still see the node responding to ARP requests.

Comment: What about `net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore`?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I did try this previously, but no luck with this either

Comment: Then there's arp_filter which requires to be used along ip rules. That's fine because since you have an additional routing table, you're using ip rules. I Never used arp_ignore to filter ARP replies in "two NICs using same IP LAN while on same L2 broadcast domain" cases for example: always arp_filter. (showing those ip rules would help too).

Comment: Do you mean by this that you have set both `net.ipv4.conf.eth0.arp_ignore=3` and `net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=3` simultaneously? You should add that to your question.